# How do i show my table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is my index.php view were my table is placed

```
<table class="striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Created at</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody id="showdata">
                <!--<tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>Alvin</td>
                  <td>Eclair</td>
                  <td>$0.87</td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Edit</a>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Delete</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>-->
              </tbody>
</table>
```

This my ajax script placed on index.php

```
function showAllEmployee() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Employee/showAllEmployee',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          //console.log(data);
          var html = '';
          var i;
          for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            html += '<tr>'+
                  '<td>'+data[i].emp_id+'</td>'+
                  '<td>'+data[i].name+'</td>'+
                  '<td>'+data[i].address+'</td>'+
                  '<td>'+data[i].created_at+'</td>'+
                  '<td>'+
                    '<a href="javascript:;" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" style="margin-right: 10px;" data="'+data[i].emp_id+'">Edit</a>'+
                    '<a href="javascript:;" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" data="'+data[i].emp_id+'">Delete</a>'+
                  '</td>'+
                '</tr>';
          }
          $('#showdata').html(html);
        },
        error: function() {
          alert('Could not get data from database');
        }

      });
    }
```

This is what i have on my employee controller

```
public function showAllEmployee()
    {
        $result = $this->em->showAllEmployee();
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

This is my model

```
public function showAllEmployee()
    {
        $this->db->order_by('created_at', 'desc');
        $query = $this->db->get('tbl_employees');
        if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Whenever i refresh the page the data wont display instead i run into an error could not get the data from the database which is the condition i set on my ajax script what could be wrong pls help

Comment: if the ajax script hit the controller then the script is ok. ensure it hit the controller

Comment: @masum billah I'm sure of this url i can as well view my json data

Comment: How you are calling JS Function `showAllEmployee()`? And use `type: 'get',` instead of using `ajax`.

Comment: @Rohan Kumar inside this function $(function(){ showAllEmployee(); });

Comment: when(which event) you call showAllEmployee().

Comment: Is there any errors shown in your browser's console?

Comment: @Rohan Kumar i check twice the console there's none

Comment: @masum billah i just want it to show the data whenever i get to the page there's no event

Comment: Try an alert before `$('#showdata').html(html);` like `alert(html)` and see if is working? If it works, then may be your `tbody` has property `display:none`.

Comment: i did try to alert(html) but it still direct me to my condition where if there's an error could not get the data from the database

Comment: if console.log(top of success function) print data that means everything is ok just presentation problem. but it call ajax error function that means controller issue(controller response related)

Comment: @masum billah i can view my json data whenever I direct into my controller's method showAllEmployee

Comment: check console for error or use firebug.

Comment: @hrishi my browser is mozillar firefox I just go to inspect element and check the console tab is that the one ur refering?

Comment: yes. Is there any error

Comment: @hrishi none. I'm used on creating crud using jquery ajax I had one project who uses modal it's working fine. but this one i dont know what's wrong because there's no error

Comment: are you getting the table when you land on the page first time ?

Comment: @Himanshu Upadhyay yes i can see my table headings but the data that was supposed to pass by my ajax script is not displaying on the table

Comment: I'm guessing this line is failing: ``$query = $this->db->get('tbl_employees');``
Have you added code to determine whether ``$query`` is valid?

Comment: @kmoser when i put the go the method of my controller i can view my json data

Comment: @Lestah can you see this response HTML data into your network tab of inspect element ?

Comment: @Himanshu Upadhyay I'm on my network tab what do i need to look for?

Comment: Keep it open and refresh the page. It should initiate ajax request there and tell me what do you see there?!!

Comment: @Himanshu Upadhyay I can see status method file domain cause and type tab on the network

Comment: @Lestah there will be several sub-tabs under network tab. Like All, Html, Css, JS.... but you need to look at XHR one. Keep it open and refresh the page and tell me what do you see there. Better if you can paste it here.

Comment: @Himanshu Upadhyay there's nothing on the XHR tab

Comment: It means your ajax request is not being initiated.

Comment: @Lestahyour headers and TD are not same. you have 4 header and 5 td.

Comment: Try ``alert( '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Employee/showAllEmployee' )``, then paste that URL into another browser tab and see what it produces. Does that give you valid JSON data?

Answer (score 0):

set header as JSON type in the controller
change your controller to

```
public function showAllEmployee(){
    $result = $this->em->showAllEmployee();
    $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode($result));
}
```